# Fetch database comments using hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate

I need to fetch database comments from a postgresql using hibernate. I have read the documentation but could not find any hints on how to get the comments. Basically I am generating Pojos and would like to use the comments in the database to put them into the Java classes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems hibernate does fetch DB comments when using the hbm2hbmxml tool but is not using that when generating POJOs (hbm2java). You can override the freemarker templates used to generate POJOs and add the comments there.